# How to create a checkbox for Outlook-Addin near "New-Mail" Button

Tags: c#, checkbox, outlook

I want to create a CheckBox for "New Mails" near the Send-Button.

[image]

Here is my CustomUI.xml Code.

```html
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="grpTabAddIns"
               label="E-Mail2">
          <button id="btnEinstellungenOeffnen"
                  label="Einstellungen"
                  getImage="GetImage"
                  showImage="true"
                  size="large"
                  supertip="Abrufen und Ändern der Einstellungen des E-Mail2 Add-Ins"
                  onAction="btnEinstellungenOeffnen_Click"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <button id="btnZuordnungContextMenu"
              label=" Zuordnung erstellen/ändern"
              getImage="GetImage"
              showImage="true"
              supertip=" Zuordnung erstellen/ändern"
              onAction="btnZuordnung_Click"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Is it possible to set a CheckBox in yellow place?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. The ribbon UI is on the top of the compose area. There you may place your custom UI.

However, you may consider replacing the default Outlook's UI with your own form where you may place To, CC, BCC and other fields on your own leaving only the ribbon UI as is. The [Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019) provide the Replace-all layout which replaces the whole Outlook form with the form region.

Also, you may consider using [Advanced Outlook view and form](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php) regions provided by Add-in Express.